# pie chart update or how to send values from gridview to pie chart to update

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

I am using dojo pie chart in my application.. 
I have dojo pie chart and bar grpah... My questions is now i need to update those two things..
that is.. above the charts I have gridview with user data.. I need to pass certain values from gridview to pie chart or bar grpahs to update..using javascript or jquery

Answer (score 1):

Try the new [DataPresentation](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/widget/DataPresentation) widget

Comment: I hope here just he is showing the how % value held on each month in grid? but I need to have something like to click on grid to change grpah.. 

Thanks

Comment: both widgets use a dojo.data source.  Changes would update both widgets appropriately.